# In equilateral triangle,One vertex of a square is at the midpoint of the side, and the two adjacent vertices are on the other two sides of triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In the equilateral triangle $ABC,AB=12.$One vertex of a square is at the midpoint of the side $BC$, and the two adjacent vertices are on the other two sides of the triangle.Find the length of the side of the square.

---

Let $DEFG$ be the square.Let $D$ be the midpoint of the side $BC.BD=DC=6.$
Let $E$ be on the side $AC$ and $G$ be on the side $AB$ such that $AG=12-a,BG=a$ and $AE=12-b,EC=b$.
In triangle $DEC,$ applying Cosine law,
$\cos 60^\circ=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{b^2+36-DE^2}{12b}........(1)$
In triangle $DGB,$ applying Cosine law,
$\cos 60^\circ=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{a^2+36-DG^2}{12a}........(2)$
I am stuck here.

Comment: You must have $BG=EC$, so side length is just $\frac{6\sin 60}{\sin 75}\approx 5.38$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1) $\triangle ADB: \angle D=90^{\circ}, DB=6, AD=\sqrt{12^2-6^2}=\sqrt{108}, AB=12$

2) $DG - $ bisector $\angle ADB$

$$DG=\sqrt2 \frac{AD \cdot DB}{AD+DB}=\sqrt2 \frac{6\sqrt3 \cdot 6}{6\sqrt3+6}=\frac{6\sqrt6}{\sqrt3+1}=3\sqrt6(\sqrt3-1)$$

Comment: You introduced a spurious $\sqrt6$ right at the end.

Comment: @Roman83 the question seems to require that E and F be on the triangle sides

Comment: @almagest: Thank you!

Comment: I want to ask one thing ,how did you know $AD$ is perpendicular to $BC$ and why $F$ came on $AD$?@Roman83

Comment: @GCab No. The two vertices adjacent to the vertex at $D$. Roman83's triangle is rotated!

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia: The square and equilateral triangle are symmetric figures

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia please make clear the "adjacent" .. to D, or to each other ? in your question

Comment: They are adjacent to $D$@GCab

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be length of side of square.Triangles DBG and CDE are congruent because they have an angle and two corresponding sides which are equal.Implies BG=EC.In which case Angle BDG = $45^0$ and Angle BGD = $75^0$.Applying sine rule in Triangle BGD $$\frac{x}{\sin{60^0}}=\frac{6}{\sin{75^0}}$$
I hope this was helpful.

Comment: A neat solution.

Comment: By which similarity criteria,you proved triangles $DBG$ and  $CDE$ similar.Because there are only three similarity criterias,$SSS,AAA,SAS$.@VarunKumar

Comment: @Vinod Kumar Punia he appears to have used ASS congruence, which only exists in the case of right angles (as RHS). I think it Is a mistake..